# Hive - XML- Serde - Key Value Pair - Create table

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive, hive-serde

Key Value pair combination. We are trying to explode the ID as a column name and VALUE as the corresponding data for each column.

```
`<CT> <items> <item> <field> <id>Column1</id> <value>25672</value> </field> 
 <field> <id>Column2</id> <value>FGE</value> </field> <field> 
 <id>Column3</id> <value>Florence to Venice</value> </field> </item> 
 </items> 
 </CT>`
```

We are expecting to create a table as below,
Expected Output:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
25672   FGE     Florence to Venice
```

We tried using Map to extract the key value pair but we are not getting the desired result.

```
'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dev.reference_test(
PM_SubCollection array<map<string,string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
"column.xpath.PM_SubCollection"="/CT/items/item/field",
"xml.map.specification.id"="#id->#value"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/dev/reference_test'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="",
"xmlinput.end"=""
);'


Output:
'[{"field":"Column125672"},{"field":"Column2FGE"},{"field":"Column3Florence to Venice"}]'
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Not going to happen. The columns should be known in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If we know the columns and create the table with the expected columns, can  we map the value part of it to the respective columns?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/issues/42

If you have to capture the message id as well as id and value from the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CT>
   <messageID>11736</messageID>
   <items>
      <item>
         <field>
            <id>Column1</id>
            <value>25672</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <id>Column2</id>
            <value>FGE</value>
         </field>
         <field>
            <id>Column3</id>
            <value>Florence to Venice</value>
         </field>
      </item>
   </items>
</CT>
```

Then I would go with the DDL which looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xml_42a;

CREATE  TABLE xml_42a(
message_id string,
fields array<struct<field:struct<id:string,value:string>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
  "column.xpath.message_id"="/CT/messageID/text()",
  "column.xpath.fields"="/CT/items/item/field"
  )
STORED AS 
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' 
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<CT>",
"xmlinput.end"="</CT>"
);

load data local inpath '/Users/dvasilen/Misc/XML/42a.xml' OVERWRITE into table xml_42a;

select * from xml_42a;
```

and here is the output:

```
hive> 
    > select * from xml_42a; 
OK
11736   [{"field":{"id":"Column1","value":"25672"}},{"field":{"id":"Column2","value":"FGE"}},{"field":{"id":"Column3","value":"Florence to Venice"}}]
Time taken: 0.08 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```